# WCF Implementation in base class, PrincipalPermission Role in derived classes?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inheritance, principalpermission

I have a few WCF services that all implement an All() method, so I made a generic base class that implements that All() method, but every WCF service call needs his own security role.

```
public class QueryService<T> 
    where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        // query data
        return data;
    }
}

public class CarService : QueryService<Car>
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Car_R")]
    public new IQueryable<Car> All()
    {
        return base.All();
    }
}

public class BikeService : QueryService<Bike>
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Bike_R")]
    public new IQueryable<Bike> All()
    {
        return base.All();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to move the PrincipalPermission annotation to the base class (QueryService) and
define the Role string in my derived classes, that way I wouldn't have to override every method 
of my base class (and call base.xxx).

Something like this: (isn't working though ...)

```
public class QueryService<T> 
    where T : class
{
    public const string RoleFromDerivedClass = "Default";

    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = RoleFromDerivedClass)]
    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        // query data
        return data;
    }
}

public class CarService : QueryService<Car>
{
    public const string RoleFromDerivedClass = "Car_R";
}

public class BikeService : QueryService<Bike>
{
    public const string RoleFromDerivedClass = "Bike_R";
}
```